# Yum search software name

Tags: linux, yum

I forgot a command with SSH which could search software name.

For explain: If I want install `mysql-server`, but I want choose a version before `yum install`. This command can make a search (return all the software contains `mysql`), then a list return like:

```
mysql-5.0.77-4.tar.gz 
mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386.rpm
...
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSH.

Comment: Or programming. Did you try `yum search`?

Comment: @larsmans , I remember I have used before, but now I forgot it.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, right, that is that, thanks. foolish me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, this is not related to SSH, but a function of your package manager, `yum`.

You can use `yum search` or `yum list`.

> list           List a package or groups of packages
>
> search         Search package details for the given string

(From the yum help).

Answer (score 0):

You are not searching with "ssh". You are searching with `yum`. http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-searching-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is wrong:

SSH is a network-protocol, which provides a shell to a remote system.

I think you are looking for something like:

```
man -q mysql
```

[rpm-howto](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html)